# SQL Server: Fastest way to transform millions of rows of data from one table to multiple others

Tags: sql-server

I have a staging table with more than 6 million rows of flattened data from a CSV file that I bulk inserted.

I need to take each rows, convert various column values from `varchar` to `int`/`decimal`/`datetime`, and input each row into numerous new database tables all with foreign key relationships, for now I'll simplify this to: (`Parent`, `Child`, `OptionalChild`) .

I don't need to read it row by row, as each single row contains the parent/child/optional child flattened data.

I am currently going through the records row by row using a SELECT TOP 1, then delete each row after its processed but this is taking hours obviously.

Would appreciate some faster / more efficient approaches.

```
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @Date DATETIME2;
DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Number INT;
DECLARE @OptionalChildCode VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @OptionalChildNumber INT;

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Records)
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 1 
      @Id = Id, 
      @Date = Date, 
      @Code = Code,
      @Number = Number,
      @OptionalChildCode = OptionalChildCode,
      @OptionalChildNumber = OptionalChildNumber
   FROM Records   

   DECLARE @OutputTable AS TABLE(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Name VARCHAR(10))

   INSERT INTO (Parent) (ParentDate)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, 'ParentId' INTO @OutputTable(Id, Name)
   VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME2,@Date, 20))

   INSERT INTO (Child)(ParentId, ChildCode, ChildNumber)
   VALUES (
      (SELECT ObjectId FROM @OutputTable WHERE Name = 'ParentId'),
      @Code,
      CONVERT(INT, @Number)
   )

   IF (@OptionalChildCode IS NULL)
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO (Child)(ParentId, ChildCode, ChildNumber)
        VALUES (
            (SELECT ObjectId FROM @OutputTable WHERE Name = 'ParentId'),
            @OptionalChildCode,
            CONVERT(INT, @OptionalChildNumber)
         )
     END 

   DELETE FROM Records WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

Records table (all columns from CSV bulk import):

```
Columns: Id INT, Date VARCHAR(50), Code VARCHAR(50), Number VARCHAR(50), OptionalChildCode VARCHAR(50), OptionalChildNumber VARCHAR(50)
```

Target tables:

```
--Parent 
Columns: (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ParentDate DATETIME2)

--Child
Columns: (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ParentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ChildCode VARCHAR(10), ChildNumber INT)
```

Sample data (a row from Records table):

```
1, "2020-01-01-00-00", "Code123", "55", "OptionalCode456", "66"
```

Expected results:

```
--Row from Parent table:
111-222-333, 2020-01-01-00-00

--Row from Child table:
333-333-333, 111-222-333, "Code123", 55

--Row from Child table from optional child:
444-444-444, 111-222-333, "OptionalCode456", 66
```

Comment: Doing this RBAR is going to be truly terrible for performance. A good data engine should be able to handle 6 million rows in a single batch pretty well, if I am honest; very likely you won't need any paging as you're separating the data into several tables. Meaningful and consumable sample data, and the results you want for said sample data will help us help you here.

Comment: I think it might help to see some sample data from this source table and desired results in your three target tables. Doing this line-by-line can't be the best way.

Comment: i've hopefully clarified some of the data type now @Larnu.

how does one go about batching queries, can you direct me to any good sources on avoid RBAR operations?

Comment: I don't see any sample data or expected results in your latest edit, @mb1231 .

Comment: @Larnu sorry should be there now

Comment: So do the rows lose their relationships? Only one example isn't particulary helpful, i must admit.

Comment: there are no relationships in the initial table (Records) outside of each row. i am creating relationships from a flat row of data in Records.

Comment: Did you consider using SSIS? It's quite handy since it provides multicasting, row splitting and so on within the dataflow - so basically you can populate all table at once. However, during the copying / population I'd suggest to disable the Foreignkeys - they will slow down the process dramatically. You can reactivate them afterwards

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is mainly that you need to get the inserted identity numbers matched against the original table, at the same time as inserting multiple child rows. You *cannot* use `OUTPUT` in an `INSERT` to output anything other than `inserted` columns.

We can start by using a hack involving `MERGE` to output the other columns.

We can then conditionally unpivot those rows in order to get one or two child rows to insert.

```sql
DECLARE @OutputTable AS TABLE(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  Code VARCHAR(10),
  Number INT,
  OptionalChildCode VARCHAR(10),
  OptionalChildNumber INT);

MERGE Parent p
USING Records r
ON 1 = 0   -- never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ParentDate)
  VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME2, r.[Date], 20))
OUTPUT inserted.Id, r.Code, CONVERT(INT, r.Number), OptionalChildCode, CONVERT(INT, r.OptionalChildNumber)
  INTO @OutputTable (Id, Code, Number, OptionalChildCode, OptionalChildNumber)
;

INSERT INTO Child
  (ParentId, ChildCode, ChildNumber)
SELECT t.Id, v.Code, v.Number
FROM @OutputTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT t.Code, t.Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.OptionalChildCode, t.OptionalChildNumber
    WHERE OptionalChildCode IS NOT NULL
) v;
```